# R - Plot moving average of arguments in column by date

Tags: r, plot, moving-average

Suppose you have a table where Result can take values {a,b,c} in the same day. How do I plot the moving averages of frequency of a, b and c across time?

Example:

```
Date         Result
2018-11-23   a
2018-11-23   a
2018-11-23   b
2018-11-24   c
2018-11-24   b
2018-11-25   c
2018-11-25   c
2018-11-25   b
2018-11-26   c
2018-11-26   b
2018-11-26   a
...
```

Comment: do you have a numeric column

Comment: @akrun I don't. Just need to see how a, b and c evolve across time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you exactly want to achieve. But the following gives you the count for each letter per date.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

x <- structure(list(date = structure(c(17858, 17858, 17858, 17859, 
                                  17859, 17860, 17860, 17860, 17861, 17861, 17861), class = "Date"), 
               letter = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "b", "c", "c", "b", "c", "b", 
                          "a")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))

agg_x <- x %>% 
  group_by(date, letter) %>%
  summarize(count = n()) %>%
  ungroup() 

agg_x %>%
  spread(letter, count)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   date           a     b     c
#>   <date>     <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 2018-11-23     2     1    NA
#> 2 2018-11-24    NA     1     1
#> 3 2018-11-25    NA     1     2
#> 4 2018-11-26     1     1     1

ggplot(data = agg_x, aes(x = date, y = count, color = letter)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This actually works for what I want. I assumed a MA because I had read a similar use and wanted to do something of the sort.